# how to set event to native calendar dynamically in android?

Tags: android

I need to set the event to the native calendar.and date and time will be provided by the user input.How can I pass the date and time values to the native calendar?
I tried a lot and Calendar.getInstance() will be helpful in setting the current date and time.
But I want to set the event for user provided dates and time.Can anybody help me in this regard?
I want the particular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.calendar_four_one;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button click;
EditText date,time;
int years,months,days,hours,mins,seconds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    date=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
    time=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTime);


    click=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String d=date.getText().toString();

            String t=time.getText().toString();

            List <String> dateTime = new ArrayList<String>();
            dateTime = getDateAndTime(d,t);
            //String str[] = new String[dateTime.size()];

            years = Integer.parseInt(dateTime.get(0));
            months = Integer.parseInt(dateTime.get(1));
            days = Integer.parseInt(dateTime.get(2));
            hours = Integer.parseInt(dateTime.get(3));
            mins = Integer.parseInt(dateTime.get(4));
            seconds = Integer.parseInt(dateTime.get(5));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+years, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

            Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
            calIntent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
            calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Google IO Afterparty");
            calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The W Hotel Bar on Third Street");
            calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Hang out after Google IO for a drink and geeky conversation.");
            Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            startTime.set(years, months-1, days, hours, mins,seconds); // (Year-2013)(Day-Wed [i.e:-3rd DOW]) (Date-16th) 15:50
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(years, months-1, days, hours, mins+30,seconds); // 18:30
            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
            startTime.getTimeInMillis());
            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
            endTime.getTimeInMillis());
            startActivity(calIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}


public List<String> getDateAndTime(String date,String time)
{

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] dateStr = date.split("/");
    String[] timeStr = time.split(":");

    for(String str:dateStr)
        list.add(str);

    for(String str:timeStr)
        list.add(str);

    return list;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}



package com.example.calendar_four_one;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
// Vibrator object
public Vibrator vibrator;
long[] pattern = { 0L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L,
    250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L };
// Ringtone object
Uri ringT;
Ringtone ringTone;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String remindText = intent.getStringExtra("text");
//Unique notification id for every alarm
int receiverID = intent.getIntExtra("AlrmId", 0);
// Notification creation
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context).setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
        .setContentTitle("Reminder").setContentText(remindText);

// Create vibrator pattern
vibrator = (Vibrator) context
        .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);// No repetition

// Notification tone creation and play
ringT = RingtoneManager
        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, ringT);
ringTone.play();
// Create toast and show on center of the screen
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, remindText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
// end of toast...

// Show status bar notification
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(receiverID, mBuilder.build());
```

}
    }

This code finally worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
intent.putExtra("title", "title");
startActivity(intent);
```

start Time and endTime are the Time values

Comment: what actually startTime and endTime contains??are they user defined variables holding date and time values?

Comment: Yes , that are the time values, end time is not needed. start time is the reminder time